how do I make multiple specific cells in a row reset number to 0 if specific cell in the same row= text, applied to all rows
(I have almost 0 vba knowledge)
example
if I have 5 rows and B, D, F, L= a number for each row  if specific text is in cell M for 2 specific rows the command resets all the numbers in the specific row and column to 0
so B2, B5, D2, D5, F2, F5, L2, L5 now equal 0 because M2, M5= specified text
I tried looking into it this is what I found and slightly modified
Sub Brexlin()

    [F2,H2,J2,L2,N2,U2,V2] = [if(AA2="MIA",0,)]

End Sub

that applies to 1 row but how do I make something like this apply to all rows
one person told me this "Basically just an if statement within a change event" but idk what to make of it with my lack of knowledge

If my understanding is correct, the next solution is for you:

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim stext$
  stext = "specific text"
  If Intersect(Target, Range("M2, M5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If [M2] = stext And [M5] = stext Then Range("B2, B5, D2, D5, F2, F5, L2, L5") = 0
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

If you change M2 or M5 of Sheet1 and both M2 and M5 contains the "specific text" (change on your own) zero writes to cells B2, B5, D2, D5, F2, F5, L2, and L5.
To do this press Alt+F11 in Excel. VBA editor opens. In the VBA Project browser on the left side, double-click on the sheet you need. The blank sheet opens (should be blank in the new sheet/workbook) on the right side. Copy and paste the code. Come back to Excel and test: enter the specific text into M2 then M5.
UPD
The next code processes all rows where "dispose" is entered to M (change it if required in two places). The columns to reset is defined in the "ctd" array.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim stext$, ctd, ca, cc, cs
  If Intersect(Target, Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  stext = "dispose"
  ctd = Array("B:B", "D:D", "F:F", "L:L")
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If IsArray(Target) Then
    For Each ca In Target.Areas
      For Each cc In Intersect(ca, Range("M:M"))
        If cc = stext Then
          For Each cs In ctd
            Range(cs).Cells(cc.Row) = 0
          Next cs
        End If
    Next cc, ca
  ElseIf Target = stext Then
    For Each cs In ctd
      Range(cs).Cells(Target.Row) = 0
    Next
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

UPD
For the last comment "say I use a formula to keep column M updated from a different sheet, how do I make it read the change in sheet 1 I type MIA which reflects in Sheet 2 column M which clears the data in sheet 2", you need to handle the Calculate event on the target sheet (you say Sheet 2):
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Dim stext$, ctd, ca, cc, cs, Target As Range
  Set Target = Intersect(Range("M:M"), Me.UsedRange)
  stext = "dispose"
  ctd = Array("B:B", "D:D", "F:F", "L:L")
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If IsArray(Target) Then
    For Each cc In Target.Cells
      If cc = stext Then
        For Each cs In ctd
          Range(cs).Cells(cc.Row) = 0
        Next
      End If
    Next
  ElseIf Target = stext Then
    For Each cs In ctd
      Range(cs).Cells(Target.Row) = 0
    Next
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


lets pretend all rows whether it be 5 or 1000 are the same type but lets say I type in text into say 3 of 5 rows containing a set of numbers 2 rows of specific cells will keep the same numbers 3 will revert to 0 since it contains the specific text

Unfortunately, I don't understand what you are saying.

Can you describe the required algorithm stricter? E. g. (one of variants I can guess) if, in any row (in the range of 5 to 1000), the specified text has been entered in the cell M, cells B, D, F, and L should be set to 0. Be more definitive. E. g. I need to process rows 5 to 100. The new value enters to cell M. It should be compared with the text specimen (this part is about clear, LOL). And so on.

Did you be able to run the code I provided? Does it process new entries to M2 and M5 only?

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1244256433332293653/1323043196506476586/Screenshot_2024-12-29_133932.png?ex=6773137f&is=6771c1ff&hm=b9dab0f251f06a5c9db9a5203e9e2851ec47c7de8d3f6f2d4892e8e999e259d9&
so like in this chart I type the word Dispose into L6 and L8 so it resets the data to 0 in a few specific cells.
I want a script that search through lets say 1000 rows for ones that have dispose next to them and then reset the specific cells in those rows to 0

Would you like to run this script manually?

or if I can id like to automate it if I type the specific word in this case dispose

automatic preferably but wouldnt hurt to know a script to run manually

Not a problem at all with any of it. But you need to understand the scenario which will be in place. Ones you enter "dispose" the script automatically dispose some cells in this row, or you fill out all rows you need first then run the script to process all marked rows.

dispose is just a specific text to make it change. what it would do is just reset those specific cells to 0

Still not clear but give me some time to propose a variant.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1244256433332293653/1323050420431487067/Screenshot_320.png?ex=67731a39&is=6771c8b9&hm=913d41af97427a30f49cd11ad4501f0f18d75221e8f6928d522ff9c0dda5489c&
Image link

Let's test the updated code. You can select a single cell or few consecutive or not consecutive cells to enter the keyword.

worked well thanks!

I just realized an issue. it doesnt update based on inputted text. it updates if any text at all is inputted not just MIA

After all, we forget about this condition. I've modified the code.

Sorry I have 1 more question. say I use a formula to keep column M updated from a different sheet,  how do I make it read the change
in sheet 1 I type MIA which reflects in Sheet 2 column M which clears the data in sheet 2
if at all possible

Pls. check the new update.
